# How to keep my function alive while I iterate through all the documents in a collection?

Tags: node.js, promise, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have around 100 documents under a collection and am trying to go through all of them to check if a field is greater than 0. If it is, decrement it, if it isn't move on to the next doc. The function however stops executing due to status code 200 somehow.

````js
exports.decrementDaysLeft = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.send(startDecrementing());
});

function startDecrementing() {
    db.collection('PremiumUsers').get().then(snapshot => {
        if (!snapshot.empty) 
        {
            console.log("Query Size " + snapshot.size)
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                console.log("Checking for user " + doc.id);
                decrementDaysLeftForUser(doc.id);
            })
            return 200;
        }

    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return 400;
    });
};

function decrementDaysLeftForUser(email) {
    var userColl = db.collection('PremiumUsers/' + email + '/subscribedSubjects');
     userColl.get().then(snapshot => {
        if (!snapshot.empty) {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                var num = Number(doc.data().daysLeft);
                if (num > 0) {
                    console.log('Checking ' + doc.id);
                    doc.ref.update({
                        daysLeft: (num - 1).toString()
                    }).then(function () {
                        console.log("Decremented " + doc.id + " for " + email);
                    }).catch(err => {
                        log.console(err);
                    })
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Days left is zero ' + doc.data().daysLeft);
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            console.log('No subjects');
        }
    })
};```
````

Comment: Well, your function doesn't wait for all the `decrementDaysLeftForUser()` calls to be finished before fulfilling the promise it returns.

Comment: How do you suggest I make it wait? Can you suggest the changes?

Comment: Your function needs to send a response only after **all** the asynchronous work in your function is complete. You will need to make use of the promises returned by the functions the return them.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response was sent before the `decrementDaysLeftForUser()` finishes its execution. You need to wait for it to finish the execution before sending out the response.

Using the await keyword makes sure it waits for the awaited function `decrementDaysLeftForUser()` to finish before continuing the execution of the current function `startDecrementing()`. Notes: await keyword can only be used inside async function. The code will look like this:

````
exports.decrementDaysLeft = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.send(startDecrementing());
});

function startDecrementing() {
    db.collection('PremiumUsers').get().then(async (snapshot) => {
        if (!snapshot.empty) 
        {
            console.log("Query Size " + snapshot.size)
            for(let doc of snapshot) {
                console.log("Checking for user " + doc.id);
                await decrementDaysLeftForUser(doc.id);
            }
            return 200;
        }

    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return 400;
    });
};

async function decrementDaysLeftForUser(email) {
    var userColl = db.collection('PremiumUsers/' + email + '/subscribedSubjects');
     userColl.get().then(snapshot => {
        if (!snapshot.empty) {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                var num = Number(doc.data().daysLeft);
                if (num > 0) {
                    console.log('Checking ' + doc.id);
                    doc.ref.update({
                        daysLeft: (num - 1).toString()
                    }).then(function () {
                        console.log("Decremented " + doc.id + " for " + email);
                    }).catch(err => {
                        log.console(err);
                    })
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Days left is zero ' + doc.data().daysLeft);
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            console.log('No subjects');
        }
    })
};```
````

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting the following error in spite of adding async before the function - SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: I'm still getting the same exact error for some reason

Comment: Did you add the async before the function `decrementDaysLeftForUser`? I edited that part later

Comment: still getting the same error but should have mentioned earlier the error is in this line    await decrementDaysLeftForUser(doc.id);

Comment: Does it have something to do with the fact that the line is inside a lambda function?

Comment: @KoushikBoinepally Yes. You need to make the caller function an async function too

Comment: @KoushikBoinepally I am not particularly familiar with the google-cloud-firestore part of the question, but the general idea is that you can use async/ await (which is a syntactic sugar for Promise) to wait an execution to be done first. I would recommend you to read this [article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-master-async-await-with-this-real-world-example-19107e7558ad) to better understand it

Comment: @KoushikBoinepally I edited the answer again. Can you try if it solves the problem?

Comment: I changed the forEach loop to for...of loop, as forEach doesn't work well with synchronous function. [see here](https://www.coreycleary.me/why-does-async-await-in-a-foreach-not-actually-await/)

Comment: await decrementDaysLeftForUser(doc.id) -- await is only valid in async function

Comment: FYI, you may use Promise.all() in this case.

Comment: @Andy I even added async before startDecrementing() but still same error

Comment: @Renaud Where does the Promise.all() go in this case?

Comment: You build an array of promises with `snapshot.forEach()` and then you call `Promise.all(thisPromisesArray)` which returns a promise

Comment: @KoushikBoinepally Try with the most recent edit. It shouldn't have the await SyntaxError anymore. Promise.all() allows you to input a list of Promise and it will continue the execution after all the promise resolves.

Comment: db.collection('PremiumUsers').get().then(async(snapshot) => {
Unexpected token (

Comment: Its referring to the '(' before snapshot

Comment: @Andy Can you help me with the Promise.all() approach instead?

Comment: @KoushikBoinepally There is an extra ')' after the for...of loop. line 8 of function `startDecrementing`

Comment: That's right I got this error after I removed that extra ')'

Comment: @KoushikBoinepally `Unexpected token (` means there is a SyntaxError. Can you double check your code?

Comment: @Andy I just did no syntax errors.. IDE would have caught it anyway

Comment: @KoushikBoinepally I believe there is nothing wrong with the code above, nor can I debug it without being able to run it myself. Can you try copy-and-paste one more time to see if it works?